# How can i write excel formula in power BI dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can i write below formula in DAX in PBI

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C2)>1,C2,"-")
```

Above formula showcases that if count of any record is >1 then it should come in another column

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
=
IF (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            Table,
            Table[Column] = EARLIER ( Table[Column] )
        )
    ) > 1 ,
    Table[Column],
    "-"
)
```